# Ругулярка для получения ID

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть ссылки вида

https://detail.1688.com/offer/585599875566.html

http://detail.m.1688.com/page/index.htm?offerId=585599875566

Нужно составить регулярку, чтобы вытаскивала ID товара, в данном случае это 585599875566

Comment: `(\d+)(\D+)?$`  ну вы бы хоть сами попробовали

Comment: вам в помощь - https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно учитывать символы `/` и `=` слева от чисел, тогда шаблон можно записать так:

```
$str = 'https://detail.1688.com/offer/585599875566.html
http://detail.m.1688.com/page/index.htm?offerId=585599875566';

$numbs = [];

if (preg_match_all('~(?:/|=)\K\d+~', $str, $numbs)) {
    $numbs = $numbs[0];
}

var_dump( $numbs );
```

---

Результат:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '585599875566' (length=12)
  1 => string '585599875566' (length=12)
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/aciTkl/1)

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)

Comment: @Bykuznec а вот так будет в два раза быстрее: [`~[/=]\K\d+~`](https://regex101.com/r/aciTkl/2)